# How do I change the unreadable dark blue color Cygwin uses for directories?

Tags: cygwin, colors

I'd like to change the blue color that Cygwin uses for directories. It is too dark to read on most screens.

Comment: echo -ne '\e]4;4;#00BFBF\a'   # blue

Running that command in the terminal will change the color to cyan, if you are using mintty

You can change all of the colors: http://code.google.com/p/mintty/wiki/Tips#Changing_colours  (Will move to answer when rep allows.)

Comment: Cygwin's ls doesn't use color 4 (dark blue) for directories, but color 12 (bold blue). Are you remoting to some other system?

Comment: _Cygwin uses for directories_ : The Cygwin itself has no preferences for colours. Colouring is done by the the programs which produce output, and you have to define the colours depending on the respective program. You can verify this by doing a `echo *` : You will see that the directories are not coloured differently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably get the colors from `ls` itself. You get this from invoking it as `ls --color`. You can either disable this alias, or you can change the colors. I find the colors useful, so I change the colors.

There are defaults, but you can override these by use of the `LS_COLORS` environment variable. You can set this manually, or you can use the tool [dircolors](http://linux.die.net/man/5/dir_colors) to help you.

Comment: For the curious: This not only works in Cygwin, but also on the Linux shell. So it might be useful for xterm users, too ;)

Comment: Yes, I found the colors were coming from my [remote CentOS server](http://www.serverschool.com/operating-systems/how-to-change-directory-colors-in-centos/).

I put a copy of `/etc/DIR_COLORS` in my home directory, and changed `DIR 01;34 # directory`.

Answer (score 40):

If you're using MinTTY (which you almost certainly are, unless you know you're doing something special), the easiest method is to change your MinTTY settings. You can do this by editing your `~/.minttyrc` file.

Try running the below from within a Cygwin shell (which would be what you get when you start Cygwin using the Desktop or Start Menu link), then restarting MinTTY:

```
echo 'Blue=127,127,255' >> ~/.minttyrc
echo 'BoldBlue=191,191,255' >> ~/.minttyrc
```

This will work for everywhere that blue colour turns up, not just in the results from `ls`.

Comment: I had blue comments in vim as well, which this fix remedies.

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much. That was annoying.

Comment: But the settings don't persist. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/69555256/2348597

Comment: @Greg the settings *should* persist; there's clearly something odd going on for you that means the normal solution isn't working. But I couldn't say what without a lot more detail.

Answer (score 4):

There is also a command line option `--option` that allows you to change colours

E.g. The following changes the blue to something more readable

```
C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe --option Blue=128,128,192 -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of looking at this problem is that the default "Dark Blue" color used by CMD Powershell Bash etc. on Windows is too dark. You can change it by:

- Click the top right icon
- Click Properties
- Click the Colors tab
- Select the 2nd Dark Blue color
- Change Blue: 128 to 255
- Hit tab to save the value
- Select the original background color (Usually black)
- Click OK